# Creating a generic extension method to provide filtering functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, extension-methods

I'm working on an extension method to provide filtering capabilities for several entities. The entities involved are of different types but have common fields that can be searched on.

The below is working at the moment, however I was wondering if this could be "genericized" so that the casting from generic to explicit type doesn't need to occur?

```
public static IQueryable<T> PriceLow<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, decimal? priceLow)
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Entity1))
    {
        var innerQuery = (IQueryable<Entity1>) query;
        var results = priceLow.HasValue ? innerQuery.Where(o => (o.ListPrice > priceLow.Value)) : innerQuery;
        return (IQueryable<T>) results;
    }

    if (typeof(T) == typeof(Entity2))
    {
        var innerQuery = (IQueryable<Entity2>)query;
        var results = priceLow.HasValue ? innerQuery.Where(o => (o.ListPrice > priceLow.Value)) : innerQuery;
        return (IQueryable<T>)results;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Example usage:

```
    var foo = _repository.GetAllEntity1().PriceLow(_searchCritera.PriceLow);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change the two entity types to implement a common interface which has the shared properties/methods, then you can use a generic type constraint. This would also work with a shared base class.

Do that, and then your signature looks like this (cluttering details omitted):

```
public static IQueryable<T> PriceLow<T>(...)
  where T : ICommonInterface
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, had a knowledge gap on how to specify the common base class to the method (where T : ICommonInterface)

Answer (score 2):

How about making your entities inherit from a base type that holds the searchable fields.  That way your filter method only needs to know about the one base type.

Comment: If you remove the generic-ness by just making it work on the base type, you'll essentially prevent further chaining. Since it will return an `IQueryable` of the base type, a cast would be required to chain a call specific to one of the sub-types.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to define an interface and add that interface as one of the things your class inherits from. The interface doesn't need to contain anything at all. It could just be used as a marker.

Then make your extension method require the argument is that interface.

Comment: A marker interface wouldn't work, since the code is actually using a property that isn't just on `object`

Comment: Ah, right you are. So it looks like you'd need to add some common implementation to that interface.